# How do I turn a flattened 3d array of vertices to a array of triangles?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry, mesh

Hello I'm using Unity and C# along with the Mesh renderer and filter to simulate a chunk of `16*16*256` (a Minecraft chunk). Following the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJEpeUH1EMg&t=348s) as a guide.

I have 3 constants :

`Globals.CHUNK_X`(shortened to W)

`Globals.CHUNK_Y`(H)

`Globals.CHUNK_Z`(D)

I also have a function `Globals.c3to1(x, y, z)` which converts a 3d index to a 1d index in a `(W+1)*(H+1)*(D+1)` array of vertices by returning the following `(H+1) * (W+1) * z + (W+1) * y + x`.

I arranged my vertices in a 1d array of dimensions `(W+1)*(H+1)*(D+1)` called `vertices` such that `vertices[c3to1(x, y, z)] = (x, y, z)`. Now that I have my vertices how do I go along getting all the triangles into an array. I have created a for loop to go along with.

```cs
/*How the array of vertices were created.*/
        vertices = new Vector3[(Globals.CHUNK_X + 1) * (Globals.CHUNK_Y + 1) * (Globals.CHUNK_Z + 1)];
        for (int z = 0; z <= Globals.CHUNK_Z; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y <= Globals.CHUNK_Y; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x <= Globals.CHUNK_X; x++) {
                    int index = Globals.c3to1(x, y, z);
                    vertices[index] = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                }
            }
        }
```

```cs
/*How do I go about doing this triangles array*/
        triangles = new int[36 * (Globals.CHUNK_X + 1) * (Globals.CHUNK_Y + 1) * (Globals.CHUNK_Z + 1)];
        for (int z = 0; z < Globals.CHUNK_Z; z++) { //For each aisle
            for (int y = 0; y < Globals.CHUNK_Y; y++) { //For each row
                for (int x = 0; x < Globals.CHUNK_X; x++) { //For each column
                    for (int i = 0, index = 0; i < 6; i++) { //For each 6 faces
                        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++, index++) { //For each 6 points of each face
                            //triangles[36 * Globals.c3to1(x, y, z) + index] = ?;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

For those wondering why the vertices is `17*17*257` instead of `16*16*256` it is bc there is an additional vertex on each row, column, and aisle (2 adjoined cubes have 3 vertices on the joined edge, 3 have 4, 4 have 5 and so on).

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? This is about 2 million triangles, where most of them are not visible anyway. What are you trying to achieve? Would it be an option to display only triangles on the surface?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I think Unity has some sort of culling because I tried doing this before but ending up with a 14*16*256 instead of a 16*16*256, but still managed to get more than 2000fps. I think Unity doesn't care about the invisble triangles, but thats just me.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, people just specify cube triangles manually. Adding loops is not very beneficial because they will be very short and the logic becomes pretty convoluted:

```
int nextIndex = 0;
// index offsets that are equivalent to increasing x/y/z by 1
int stepX = Globals.c3to1(1, 0, 0);
int stepY = Globals.c3to1(0, 1, 0);
int stepZ = Globals.c3to1(0, 0, 1);
for (int z = 0; z < Globals.CHUNK_Z; z++) { //For each aisle
    for (int y = 0; y < Globals.CHUNK_Y; y++) { //For each row
        for (int x = 0; x < Globals.CHUNK_X; x++) { //For each column
            int baseVertex = Globals.c3to1(x, y, z);

            // front face
            triangles[nextIndex++] = baseVertex;
            triangles[nextIndex++] = baseVertex + stepY;
            triangles[nextIndex++] = baseVertex + stepX;

            triangles[nextIndex++] = baseVertex + stepX;
            triangles[nextIndex++] = baseVertex + stepY;
            triangles[nextIndex++] = baseVertex + stepX + stepY;

            // repeat equivalently for other faces
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK I get what your answer is, thanks for that, however I'm getting an extra row of elongated triangles on the back of one of the faces. I will attach the images here 1 min.

Comment: Here are the images for the problem. Forwards: https://imgur.com/a/2A5SJ4z Backwards: https://imgur.com/a/OjxUYey

Comment: One of your indices is probably off. If you don't find which one, comment out one triangle at a time and see when the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not yours, but it illustrates what you want to know.
So if you go through this code then you will find your answer.

About this code :
This is a C# script for creating a Cylindrical Mesh at Runtime

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cylinder : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private float radius = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float height = 4.0f;

    [SerializeField]
    private int VerticalSubdivisions = 10;
    [SerializeField]
    private int HorizontalSubdivisions = 4;


    private void Start()
    {
        CreateCylinder();
    }

    void CreateCylinder()
    {
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[VerticalSubdivisions * (HorizontalSubdivisions + 2) + 2];

        float delta_angle = Mathf.PI * 2 / VerticalSubdivisions;
        float delta_height = height / (HorizontalSubdivisions + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < (HorizontalSubdivisions + 2); j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < VerticalSubdivisions; i++)
            {
                vertices[1 + i + j * VerticalSubdivisions] = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(delta_angle * i) * radius, delta_height * j - height * 0.5f, Mathf.Sin(delta_angle * i) * radius); 
            }
        vertices[0] = new Vector3(0, -height * 0.5f, 0);
        vertices[vertices.Length - 1] = new Vector3(0, height * 0.5f, 0);

        int[] triangles = new int[6 * VerticalSubdivisions * (HorizontalSubdivisions + 1) + VerticalSubdivisions * 2 * 3];

        for (int i = 0; i < (VerticalSubdivisions - 1); i++)
        {
            triangles[i * 3 + 0] = 0;
            triangles[i * 3 + 1] = i + 1;
            triangles[i * 3 + 2] = i + 2;
        }
        triangles[(VerticalSubdivisions - 1) * 3 + 0] = 0;
        triangles[(VerticalSubdivisions - 1) * 3 + 1] = 1 + VerticalSubdivisions - 1;
        triangles[(VerticalSubdivisions - 1) * 3 + 2] = 1;

        int lower_cap_tris_offset = 3 * VerticalSubdivisions;
        for (int j = 0; j < (HorizontalSubdivisions + 1); j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VerticalSubdivisions; i++)
            {
                int index = lower_cap_tris_offset + j * VerticalSubdivisions * 6 + 6 * i;
                triangles[index + 0] = 1 + i + VerticalSubdivisions * j;
                triangles[index + 1] = 1 + VerticalSubdivisions * (j + 1) + i;
                triangles[index + 2] = 1 + VerticalSubdivisions * (j + 1) + i + 1;

                triangles[index + 3] = triangles[index + 2];
                triangles[index + 4] = 1 + i + VerticalSubdivisions * j + 1;
                triangles[index + 5] = 1 + i + VerticalSubdivisions * j; 
            }
            int __index = lower_cap_tris_offset + j * VerticalSubdivisions * 6 + 6 * (VerticalSubdivisions - 1);
            triangles[__index + 0] = 1 + VerticalSubdivisions - 1 + VerticalSubdivisions * j;
            triangles[__index + 1] = 1 + VerticalSubdivisions * (j + 1) + VerticalSubdivisions - 1;
            triangles[__index + 2] = 1 + VerticalSubdivisions * (j + 1); 
            triangles[__index + 3] = triangles[__index + 2];
            triangles[__index + 4] = 1 + VerticalSubdivisions * j;
            triangles[__index + 5] = 1 + VerticalSubdivisions - 1 + VerticalSubdivisions * j; 
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < VerticalSubdivisions - 1; i++)
        {
            int index = 3 * VerticalSubdivisions + VerticalSubdivisions * 6 * (HorizontalSubdivisions + 1); 
            triangles[index + i * 3 + 0] = 1 + VerticalSubdivisions * (HorizontalSubdivisions + 1) + i;
            triangles[index + i * 3 + 1] = vertices.Length - 1;
            triangles[index + i * 3 + 2] = 1 + VerticalSubdivisions * (HorizontalSubdivisions + 1) + i + 1;
        }
        int _index = 3 * VerticalSubdivisions + VerticalSubdivisions * 6 * (HorizontalSubdivisions + 1) + (VerticalSubdivisions - 1) * 3;
        triangles[_index + 0] = 1 + VerticalSubdivisions * (HorizontalSubdivisions + 1) + VerticalSubdivisions - 1;
        triangles[_index + 1] = vertices.Length - 1;
        triangles[_index + 2] = 1 + VerticalSubdivisions * (HorizontalSubdivisions + 1); 


        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh; 
        mesh.Clear();

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }

}
```

Hope it helps to you !